# How to allow two applets to work that use different jre's

Tags: java, applet

Got two applets.

- Applet A requires 1.6+
- Applet B doesn't work in 1.6 (1.4 works)

How do I get them both to work?

Comment: Why doesn't applet B work in 1.6? I thought Sun was big on backward compatibility.

Comment: They run into several issues.  It doesn't so much "not launch" as much as have severe usability issues that are unacceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I could control applet B, I could specify it to use the 1.4 JRE.

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/family-clsid.html

Comment: That's how to do it alright. Now why is it that you don't control the launch behaviour of applet B? What's stopping you copying the <applet> or <object> tag with suitable modifications into a webpage of your own and advertise that as the new launch for applet B?

Comment: That applet is controlled entirely third party.

Comment: Then you are SOL. An applet will always use the latest JRE installed unless a clsid is put into its launch tag. :(

Answer (score 0):

From 6u10 there is an out-of-process plug-in. This allows multiple JRE processes to run and so version selection can select more than one JRE version.

Better: Make Applet B run on 1.6.

Comment: I have no control of Applet B or it's launching behavior.  I support applet A, and need it not to interfere with other mission critical applets.